# c# datetime create Day of Week Hour and Min

Tags: c#, datetime

How do i go about creating a datetime based on only the following information:
Day of Week, Hour & Minuet.

I.e. I don't care what month it is or even what the date is (i don't have that info in the database).

I thought i could parse them as a string but is turning out to be more difficult than i thought.

Comment: question makes little sense " I don't care what month it is or even what the date is " - if that's the case make up a random date on that day of week!

Comment: would that be the best option? choose some random date on a monday and work from there?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with `DateTime` variables later

Comment: If your consideration is only with day, you can choose random date.

Comment: I will end up comparing to another pulled from a database. again all the information in that is the day and time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Created on function for you it might be helpful to you ..

```
   public DateTime CreateDayOfWeek(int DayOfWeek,int hour,int min)
        {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month,DateTime.Now.Day,hour,min,0);


            // The (... + 7) % 7 ensures we end up with a value in the range [0, 6]
            int daysUntilTuesday = (DayOfWeek - (int)dt.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
            //  DateTime nextTuesday = today.AddDays(daysUntilTuesday);


            dt = dt.AddDays(daysUntilTuesday);

            return dt;
        }
```

I have tested for several dates and its working for me ..
let me know if you have any issue ..

Here is [**.netFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yaa1HM)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your date like this...

```
var hour = 1;  // you set this from code
var minute = 1;  // set this from code
var now = DateTime.Now;
var tempDateTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, hour, minute, 0);
// Make this enum whatever you want your date to be...
var num = (int)DayOfWeek.Sunday;
var dateForComparison = tempDateTime.AddDays(num - (int)tempDateTime.DayOfWeek);
```

Now dateForComparison holds a date that has your time values set and the day of week you have specified.

Answer (score 1):

You said you don't care about what month or date it is, which makes me assume you want any date as long as it is the right day of week and time (hour and minute).  You can do it like this:

```
var date = new System.DateTime(2016, 9, 25);

date = date.AddDays(dow).AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes);
```

September 25, 2016 was a Sunday.  Add the day of the week (Sunday = 0) and you get the correct day.  Then add the hours and minutes.  Of course, if you like you can pick any Sunday of any month/year to start.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function for build your date:

```
public DateTime BuildDate(Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;

            var initialDate = now.AddDays(((Int32)now.DayOfWeek + 1) * -1);

            return new DateTime(initialDate.Year, initialDate.Month, initialDate.AddDays(day).Day, hour, minute, 0);
        }
```

The day of week is start from sunday in this case.

Answer (score -2):

You can use: **DateTime.ToString Method (String)**

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd HH:mm") // for military time (24 hour clock)
```

More: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Please read question carefully before give answer.